# Gem jquery-datatables-rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

In my gemfile I included these gems:

```
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

In my application.css file I included these

```
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

In my application.js I included these

```
 //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
   $('#sort').dataTable({
       "bPaginate": false, 
       "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "<span class=icon-search></span>"

        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0 ] }
        ]     
    });
$('#sort').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
    } );

// For fluid containers
$('.datatable').dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
});
```

But I am not getting the option to search but I am getting this error

```
oCol is undefined   
oCol.fnSetData( oData, val );
```

I referred datatables.net for this.Can someone please tell me what is this error?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to your situation exactly - however I can offer a suggestion. Since I don't see `oCol` in your javascript code, it would seem this is an undefined error coming from the jquery javascript. You are either missing a required js file, or I would try reversing the order of `//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap` with `//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables` and see if that helps  (The files get included in the order specified, so if `jquery.dataTables` uses a variable that is defined in `jquery.dataTables.bootstrap`, then you would see an error like this.

EDIT: I can also offer you what we have in our configuration (we use dataTables as well)

*Our Gemfile:*

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.19'
```

*Our application.js:*

```
//= require jquery.min.js
//= require jquery_ujs.js
//= require jquery.dataTables.js
//= require ColReorder.js
//= require jquery.timers-1.2.js
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
```

**note** ColReorder.js is a dataTables plugin file

*Our application.css:*

```
*= require jquery.ui.all.css
*= require demo_table
*= require ColReorder
```

**note** The demo_table file is the css file that comes with the jquery dataTables.

**And** I should add that we actually have downloaded dataTables, and jquery-ui and we have taken the Javascript files and CSS files and actually put them in our `assets/javascripts` and `assets/stylesheets` paths.

Hope this helps!! And if not, I can try and give you some pointers to debugging where this is coming from :)

Answer (score 0):

put on gemfile

```
group :assets do

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late here I know, but I find I get this error when the number of TH and TD elements don't match, or something similar. Make sure your table is well formed, ie. the TH elements are in a THEAD and the TD's are in a TBODY.